# The monitor that's connected to the laptop through USBA-HDMI adapter blacks out when the laptop's lid is closed

Tags: windows-10, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, external-display

I have this asus laptop which has a single HDMI port to which I have one external monitor connected, and the other monitor is connected through the USBA-HDMI adapter. I notice two things:

- When both the monitors are on and connected, I don't see app notifications (including discord) on the screen.
- When I close my laptop's lid, I only see one monitor that's connected directly to the HDMI port that remains on, and the other one that's connected through the USBA-HDMI adapter shuts off/goes black, and I start seeing discord notifications in my laptop's screen.
- When I extend the monitors, the one that's connected through the USB-HDMI adapter doesn't come up though I see discord notifications in my laptop screen

Does anyone have a clue as to what's going on? Is it related to the power constrained by the USBA-HDMI adapter?

Note that I'm duplicating the displays on my laptop and the monitor that's connected to the HDMI port.

Comment: You should check what your power options are set to do with USB settings and when the lid closes.  Start > Windows System > Control Panel > System and Security > Power Options > Edit Plan Settings > Change advanced power settings > (USB settings > USB selective suspend setting) & (Power buttons and lid).  The USB selective suspend setting may be enabled and activated when you close the lid, interrupting the signal to the USB>HDMI adapter.  You can try changing these settings and see if it works more to your liking that way.

Comment: I have these settings -> https://ibb.co/7g4j5vK. It being enabled means it would suspend an individual port during times when the lid is off causing this issue? I should be disabling it then?

Comment: update: disabling it didn't work

Comment: These are just suggestions to try.  If they don't give you the intended effect, it's probably best to reset them as they were.  What are your "Power buttons and lid" settings set to do?

Comment: is this what you're referring to? https://ibb.co/hVg9C06

Comment: Yeah, that's the one.  The same settings should also be in the list where USB settings were.  I assume when you have the 3rd monitor attached, you have the laptop plugged in, and it was like that when you tested the USB setting being disabled.  In that case, it seems these settings won't help do what you want.  The issue maybe directly involving the laptop electronics / firmware and not a Windows issue.  If that's the case, you could try looking in the BIOS/UEFI firmware settings for something related to USB.

Comment: Another possible workaround would be to turn off the backlight to the laptop screen when you're using the external monitors.  The hotkeys for that are typically hold the 'Fn' key + one of the F1 - F12 keys, whichever has an icon of a screen with an X in it.

Comment: sorry, what did you mean by backlight to the laptop screen? and how what does that help in this context?

Comment: I meant turning off the backlight instead of closing the lid, to avoid the consequences of closing the lid.  Sorry I haven't been able to be more helpful.